HTTP server in C++98 recv/read not receiving correct data (TCP)
I need to write a c++ http 1.1 server and I have the problem that read/recv is not getting the data correctly. what happens is that I dont receive some bits that are necessary when receving binary files.
The output I get is

M-^IPNG^M$
^Z$
IHDR^H^FM-tM-.M-F^DsBIT^H^H^H^H|^HdM-^H^YtEXtSoftwaregnome-screenshotM-o^CM-?>tEXtCreation TimeSat 26 Oct 2024 07:34:33 PM CEST^KuM-8M-:IDAT^HM-^YcM-|M-^?M-^?M-^?^?^F$M-@M-DM-^@^F0^D$
^D^BM-FuV4ENDM-.B`M-^B

But the content I should receive is

M-^IPNG^M$
^Z$
^@^@^@^MIHDR^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^C^H^F^@^@^@M-4M-tM-.M-F^@^@^@^DsBIT^H^H^H^H|^HdM-^H^@^@^@^YtEXtSoftware^@gnome-screenshotM-o^CM-?>^@^@^@.tEXtCreation Time^@Sat 26 Oct 2024 07:34:33 PM CEST^KuM-8M-:^@^@^@^UIDAT^HM-^YcM-|M-^?M-^?M-^?^?^F$M-@M-DM-^@^F0^D^@M-B$
^D^BM-FuV4^@^@^@^@IENDM-.B`M-^B

Also when I look in the browser, then I can see from the network tab that I receive the content as it should be, but then the recv/read doesn't read the bytes that are missing (shown in the Output I get)
This is the code, that receives the content and sends the content to the POST/GET/DELETE request. Please do not comment on "Why did you write it like this. the methods should ....". I only need to understand why read/recv is not getting all the bytes. Also tried with higher read number in 'char buffer[2]'. doesn't change anything.
std::size_t len(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i++]);
    return i;
}

static char *add(char *buffer, char *to_add) {
    char *returning = (char *)malloc(len(buffer) + 3);
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i]) {
        returning[i] = buffer[i];
        i++; 
    }
    free(buffer);
    returning[i++] = to_add[0];
    returning[i++] = to_add[1];
    returning[i] = 0;
    return returning;
}

void Webserv::run(int socket) {
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    int response_content = 0;
    char buffer[2];
    int client_socket;
    char *buff;
    std::string request;

    std::cout << "Server is running and waiting for connections on port: " << port << std::endl;
    std::cout << "http://localhost:" << port << "/" << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        std::string boundary;
        int read_status = 1;
        bool loop = false;
        boundary.clear();
        client_socket = accept(socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_len);
        if (client_socket < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Error accepting connection" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        // std::cout << "Connection accepted." << std::endl;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        int temp = 0;
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        buff = (char *)malloc(1);
        buff[0] = 0;
        while (read_status != 0 && read_status != -1) {
            read_status = recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0);
            // std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
            buff = add(buff, buffer);
            request += std::string(buffer);
            if (!body(request, temp, loop, boundary))
                break;
            temp++;
        }
        std::cout << buff << std::endl;
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        // std::cout << request << std::endl;

        if (read_status == 0 || read_status == -1)
            close(client_socket);

        rq = request;
        // std::cout << request << std::endl;
        request.clear();
        int status_code = get_status_code(rq);

        if (rq.get_method() == "GET")
            response_content = GET(status_code, client_socket);
        else if (rq.get_method() == "POST")
            response_content = POST(status_code, client_socket);
        else if (rq.get_method() == "DELETE")
            response_content = DELETE(status_code, client_socket);
        else
            show_page("text/html", "error_pages/406_error_page.html", 406);
        // std::cout << response_content << std::endl;
        // request.clear();
        close(client_socket);
    }
}

It doens't matter if I use it with the C functions and a char* or with a std::string, the characters are both missing. the thing I havent tried is with a std::vector

The return value of recv() is the length of the data that was received. You're never using that. You seem to be expecting it to be a null-terminated string, but recv() processes binary data, not strings, and doesn't add a null terminator.

I'm guessing there's a null byte in the data, so add() stops there. But if not, you'll get undefined behavior because it will go past the data that was filled in by recv().

You also need to check read_status immediately after recv() returns, not on the next iteration of the while loop.

I am using the return as a break for the loop (1 line above). and the data that I get from read/recv is the buffer. how Do I get the binary data in a char * or a string (the characters that I am not getting read, like I said in the question at the beginning)

You're dealing with binary data. Use a std::vector<uint8_t> rather than a C-style string.

thanks, gonna try. gonna inform you after I tried

Im stuck here... How do I read it then? do I do recv(socket, vector<uint_8>, sizeof(vector<uint_8> - 1, 0), or how?
Or should I read in a void buffer and then moved the void buff into a uint_8 vector

The latter. You can do that in your add() function, for instance.

Another thing I don't understand: Why does add() only copy the first 2 elements of to_add.

forget about the add function. so I have to read it in a c string and then put the characters that god read into the vector?

Yes. And you'll need to pass read_status as an additional parameter, so it knows how many characters to add.

So for anyone having this problem in the future. Thanks to Barmar I could solve the issue. If you want to read without error I use this
int read() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> vector;
    int temp = 0;
    int read_status = 1;
    
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    while (true) {
        read_status = recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0);
        if (read_status == 0 || read_status == -1)
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < read_status; i++)
            vector.push_back(buffer[i]);
        for (std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it)
            request += *it;
        vector.clear();
        if (!body(request, temp, loop, boundary))
            break;
        temp++;
    }
}

bool body(std::string request, int temp, bool &loop, std::string& boundary) {
    bool found = false;

    if (temp == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    std::stringstream stream(request);
    std::string line;
    if (!loop) {
        while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
            if (line.find("boundary=") != std::string::npos) {
                std::size_t pos = line.find("boundary=");
                line.erase(0, pos + 9);
                boundary = "--" + line;
                boundary.erase(boundary.length() - 1, boundary.length());
                if (boundary[boundary.length() + 1] == 10)
                    loop = true;
                stream.clear();
                line.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (request.find(boundary + "--") != std::string::npos) {
        return false;
    }
    if (boundary.length() == 0) {
        if (request.find("\r\n\r\n") != std::string::npos) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

The body function only works with small buffersize. if you want a bigger buffer size, you have to make a check for the first iteration. I know that it is not cleanly written, but its just a prototype.

Some notes: 1) In recv(), sizeof(buffer) - 1 should be sizeof(buffer); 2) if (read_status == 0 || read_status == -1) can be just if (read_status <= 0); 3) your vector.push_back() loop can be just vector.assign(buffer, buffer+read_status); 4) your request concatenation loop can be just request.append(vector.begin(), vector.end()) or request.append((char*)vector.data(), vector.size()); 5) you don't actually need vector at all, just append the buffer directly to the request: request.append(buffer, read_status);
